# Problem installing PlayWright Chrome on Heroku using Python

Tags: python, heroku, playwright

I'm developing a WebScraping application using PlayWright, but when deploying it on heroku it can't install the browsers using the `playwright install` command I got to run the command directly on the heroku console, it does the installation but also doesn't it worked out.

I'm using buildpack
`https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack.git`

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIR56.png)

on site is working perfectly, but when you play on heroku this problem, I've tried several solutions but none worked.

code snippet.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(chromium_sandbox=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku's filesystem [is both ephemeral and dyno-local](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes made to it are lost when the dyno restarts. More importantly at the moment, when you run something like `heroku run bash` you don't connect to a running dyno. Instead, [you get a separate one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno).

Installing Chromium (or making any other filesystem changes) in such an environment will never affect what is available in your other dynos.

It looks like Playwright really wants to manage its own browser binaries. Your best bet might be to run `playwright install` near the beginning of your script, e.g. something like this:

```py
import subprocess
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

subprocess.run(["playwright", "install"])

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    # ...
```

This should make sure that the required binaries are always available at runtime.